# Wrapping ETH into WETH via ethers -- WETH coins on my balance won't appear

Tags: node.js, ethereum, ethers.js

I'm attempting to wrap ETH on Goerli into WETH by calling `deposit` function using ethers. Even though several TX already have **been confirmed and successfully mined**, nothing will appear on my WETH balance at `goerli.etherscan.io` in the dropdown `Token Holdings`. No is there `WETH` there at all, whereas there're other tokens

```
  async function myWrap(prKey) {
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(prKey, provider);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, WETH_ABI, wallet);
    const txSigner = contract.connect(wallet);

    const balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
    const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
    const balanceMinusGas = balance.sub(gasPrice.mul(ETH_GAS_LIMIT));

    let tx = txSigner.deposit({value: balanceMinusGas});
    return tx;
  }
```

What's the matter?

Moreover, at https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2 my TX-s are present.

**update1**

Additionally, I then have tried to call

```
let amount = ethers.utils.parseEther(<sum of all previous ETH-s transfers>);
contract.transfer(wallet.address, amount);
```

yet, to no avail

**update 2**

I've switched to `0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6` on Goerli. However, calling `contract.deposit()` still won't deposit any `WETH` to my wallet.

Comment: What are the values of `WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS` and `wallet.address`?

Comment: @PetrHejda WETH - `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2` and address `0x58B731F3a2E40a606b8c2E27b5FD458dA7806Efb`

Comment: @PetrHejda see the latest TXs  at https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x58b731f3a2e40a606b8c2e27b5fd458da7806efb

Answer (score 3):

The [WETH address](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2) mentioned in your comment doesn't hold any any smart contract code on the Goerli testnet. It's "just" a regular EOA address on this network.

So when you send a transaction to this address on the Goerli testnet, it simply transfers the ETH `value` - but that's it. No other interaction happens because there's no smart contract that would react to the transaction.

Having said that, the Uniswap [docs page](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments) mentions a different WETH contract address on Goerli, specifically [0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6).

**Solution**: Use the corrected WETH contract address on Goerli network.

Comment: That WETH address belongs to Uniswap, or has to do with it. Although it may work, it may include an additional fee. What I've asked about is the **direct** address of WETH  itself token/smart contract, to interract with

Comment: On the mainnet it's `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`

Comment: @mondichuk The contract linked in my answer does not impose any fees in its `deposit` and `withdraw` functions. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any other WETH contract on Goerli right now - but you can also deploy your own ERC-20 contract on the testnet that mimics the WETH behavior if that fits your use case better.

Comment: Alright, I've switched to `0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6`. However, calling `contract.deposit()` still won't deposit any WETH to my wallet